# Consulta sql de tabla en java

Tags: java, sql

Tengo que hacer una consulta a la base de datos desde java. La consulta consiste en sacar todos los nombres de trabajadores de un determinado sector:

```
Trabajador:                          Sector:

id (Int) (Clave)                     id (Int) (Clave)
nombre (Varchar(50))                 tipo (Varchar(50))
apellidos (Varchar(100))             empleado (Int) -> id del trabajador
```

En sql uso: `SELECT * FROM sector WHERE empleado=2` pero en java el id del identificador viene desde otro método, es decir, es una variable.

Trabajo sobre este código:

```
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sector WHERE empleado = ?");
 stmt.setInt(1, idEmpleado); 
 while(rs.next()) {
      int id = rs.getInt("id");
      String tipo = rs.getString("tipo");
      int empleado = rs.getInt("empleado");
      System.out.println("id = " + id + "; tipo = " + tipo + "; empleado = " + empleado);
      }
rs.close();
stmt.close();
}
```

El problema está en setInt que me lo marca en rojo:

```
Error:(32, 14) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setInt(int,long)
  location: variable stmt of type java.sql.Statement
```

y en la como sugerencia para arreglarlo (bombilla roja) sale `Rename reference`

Comment: Te lo marca en rojo, ¿qué error te está indicando? ¿está idEmpleado declarado?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar pegando el error que me muestra. Sí, viene desde el parámetro del método, además si ese fuese el problema lo rojo debería ser idEmpleado y no setInt, no?

Comment: Es correcto; en ese caso, ¿dónde está la variable `stmt2`?

Comment: El error no corresponde al código mostrado.

Comment: En todo caso, parece que te estás confundiendo entre `Statement` (la variable que creas) y `PreparedStatement` (que es la clase donde puedes hacer una consulta con placeholders -?- a los que luego aplicas valores con setInt, setLong...)

Comment: Copie el error del siguiente método en el cual tengo el mismo problema pero es una consulta diferente, perdón por el fallo

Comment: @SJuan76 podrías publicar tu propuesta de solución en la respuesta en vez de comentario para poder señalarla como solución y dejarlo más claro para otra gente que tenga la misma o similar duda

Comment: @MaríaAlonso O publica una respuesta con el código arreglado y la explicación de la solución y tras 24h podrás aceptarla tú misma :)

Comment: No tenia ni idea de que eso se podía hacer, ahora lo pongo. Gracias a todos!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN:**

Pensaba que era algo más difícil pero únicamente tenía que añadir el parámetro a la consulta, de tal forma que quedase:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sector WHERE empleado = " + idEmpleado);
```

Muchas gracias a todos, me hicisteis ver el error y buscar la solución!!